# Stripping characters from string values across multiple columns

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, strip

My question is how does one replace/strip certain characters from a string across multiple columns in a pandas data-frame? In my case it is the first three characters.

Basically I have columns which contain answers from a survey which look like this:

```
  A       B       C       D
a. w    c. y    b. x    d. z
a. w    c. y    b. x    d. z
a. w    c. y    b. x    d. z
```

and what I am trying to do is strip the answer reference character and just leave the answer like below:

```
 A     B     C     D
 w     y     x     z
 w     y     x     z
 w     y     x     z
```

I have been trying to use a list of columns I want this to happen to and then strip the first three characters (there is white-space before the actual answer). It works on a single column but not on multiple columns within the data frame:

```
cols = ['A','B','C']

df[cols] = df[cols].map(lambda x: str(x)[3:])
```

Any pointers/suggestions/info on this will be greatly appreciated.

*The csv file is read in using pandas to create the data-frame

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but i assume you asking for somthing like this:

```
>>> col1 = ['a. w','b. y','c. x']
>>> col2 = ['a. w','b. y','c. x']
>>> df=[col1,col2]
>>> result = []
>>> for x in df : result.append(map(lambda y : y[3:],x))
>>> result
[['w', 'y', 'x'], ['w', 'y', 'x']]
```